# Find distribution function and density of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Point is selected uniformly from the shape $1 \leq |x| + |y| \leq 3, y > 0$.

Find distribution function and density of random variable $X = x$.

I find that $x \in [-3; 3]$ and $y \in (0,3]$, how can i find distribution function?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

In this uniformly drawn point, let $X$ denote the first coordinate and $Y$ denote the second one.

- [Plot the region](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B1+%3C%3D+%7Cx%7C%2B%7Cy%7C+%3C%3D+3%5D) on which $X,Y$ are defined.
- Find the joint distribution function $f_{XY}$ of $X,Y$
- You can compute the marginal distribution of $X$ as
  $$
     f_X(x) = \int_\mathbb{R} f_{XY}(x,y)\ dy.
     $$